# Maven build a WAR file but build a JAR file first

Tags: eclipse, maven, war, pom.xml

I have two Maven Projects in Eclipse, both with their own POM.

Project A creates a JAR file.

Project B creates a WAR file.

When I run the "package" command against project B, I would like it to also package project A and then copy the resultant JAR file to an arbitrary location in Project B.

I have tried (and succeeded) in the copy by using the webResources value in the maven-war-plugin, like so:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources> 
      <resource> 
        <directory>../ProjectA/target</directory> 
        <targetPath>.</targetPath>
        <includes>
          <include>ProjectA*.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*shaded*.jar</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource> 
   </webResources>
```

But how can I get the POM for project B to do a build of project A?

An alternate approach that I tried was making project A a dependency of project B so it would be imported into the WEB-INF/lib directory of the WAR and then moving it elsewhere. But this seems a bit messy.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this purpose you should create a multi-module build with a structure like this.

```
  root
   +-- pom.xml
   +-- ProjectA
          +-- pom.xml
   +-- ProjectB
          +-- pom.xml
```

With a structure like the above you can handle your problem very elegant. Furthermore read about [multi-module builds](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) etc. 
One thing is to use a more up-to-date version of the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), cause the current version is 2.1.1 and not 2.0.X.

Comment: OK. Are you suggesting that the new pom.xml lives within the Eclipse project B? So project B has two poms, one that calls Project A and then its sub-directory POM ?

Comment: No. You create folder let it name "parent" and put that structure into this folder. That project will be imported into Eclipse not the separated projects. Are you using Eclipse, if yes check m2eclipse plugin. (edited the answer).

Comment: I think your approach is correct, but I need to research into multi-modules further. Thanks for the advice.